# Visual Studio C++ include all file in all subfolders of directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include

In a C++ project in Visual Studio in:

`Project Properties` > `Linker` > `Input` > `Addtional Dependencies`

I could write `$(MyEnvVar)\folderA\*.lib` to include all libraries.

But let's say folderB has many subdirectories which each has a set of header files.

If I want to include them all in one go, in:

`Project Properties` > `C/C++` > `General` > `Addtional Include Directories`

I would like to write something like: `$(MyEnvVar)\folderB\*\` or `$(MyEnvVar)\folderB\*\*\` to go one subdirectory deeper in each folder.

This doesn't seem to work.

Optionally I could do `$(MyEnvVar)\folderB\` and in my code I would include each file as `#include "name_of_subfolder\name_of_file.h"`. (This is what I want to avoid.)

Is it possible in one line to include all files in all subfolders of a certain folder?

Comment: No. And it sounds like a bad idea. It should not be nessesary to include all files in a directory.

Comment: I agree that it might sound like a bad idea, but in this special case it would just simplify a few things for me.

Comment: Wildcard expansion under windows doesn't support that, and I bet you'll get lots of comments telling you it's a terrible idea.   A more usual approach is to `#include` headers with path information (e.g. `#include "somesubdir/file.h"` and then specify only the root directory (which contains all those sub-directories) on the include path.

Comment: Yes I understand. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: As workaround you can use an include-file which will be generated by script. In Visual Studio you can configure Custom Build Tools and Custom Build Steps. Look here for more information:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434862/how-to-auto-include-all-headers-in-directory